# How can I search for text, select the line it's on, and bold it in Word VBA?

Tags: vba, button, ms-word, bold

I have created a word VBA system that takes information from excel spreadsheets and creates a word document. The document each time is a proposal for a job, so there is typically at least 1, often multiple lines that have a subtotal:

Sub-Total                                                         $1,000.00

**I want to write a piece of code (to fit in a button) that finds "Sub-Total" in the document, selects the entire line, and makes it bold.** It will always be on 1 line and the line will always start with "Sub-Total".

I tried to work with finding text, but the dollar amount changes with any new data import; only the word "Sub-Total" itself is static. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that its good practice to include a minimum, viable code sample which shows what you've tried when you're asking a stackoverflow question.

The first question is, if you're generating the Word document from Excel, why don't you format the "Sub-Total" line as you create the Word document(?); its probably easier than trying to find and format the text afterwards.

However, assuming you can't for some reason, here is a working example which opens a Word document, loops through all sentences, checks if the sentence starts with "Sub-Total ", and if it does, makes it bold. It assumes that the text (e.g. "Sub-Total $1500.00") is a complete sentence and the whole sentence needs to be bold.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindAndBold()

    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim MyWordDocument As Word.Document
    Dim Counter As Long
    
    Set WordApp = New Word.Application
    Set MyWordDocument = Word.Application.Documents.Open("C:\test.docx")
    For Counter = 1 To MyWordDocument.Sentences.Count
        With MyWordDocument.Sentences(Counter)
            If Left$(.Text, 11) = "Sub-Total: " Then
                .Bold = True
            End If
        End With
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Noted, I will include that in the future. This is the bit of code I was in search of. Thank you very much for your assistance!